# Urn with balls, distribution of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

From an urn containing $6$ balls numerated $1,\ldots,6$ we randomly choose one, then again and stop only when we picked the ball with number $1$ on it. Let $X$ be the greatest number that appeared on balls we already pulled out. What's the distribution of $X\ $? And $\mathbb{E}X=\ ?$

Comment: Sampling without replacement or with replacement?

Comment: It's not specified. Which version would be easier? :D

Comment: The no replacement version can be done by enumeration of cases, which we can do brute force, though there are shortcuts. The replacement version is not bad, but somewhat more sophisticated, since in principle the game can go a long time.

Comment: Since it says "already pulled out" I would guess it's no-replacement.

Comment: Yes, so I hope there's a different way than just to enumerate all the cases as Andre Nicolas mentioned?

Comment: I'm not quite so confident that "already pulled out" means it's without replacement.  It could mean simply that we're looking at the record including earlier trials.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm also not confident, that's just how I would interpret it. I don't have time right now to do the "with replacement" version, but I'd be interested to see what others come up with.

Comment: The result is quite messy, and I deleted my answer since I made a mistake. Thew solution if sampling is with replacement might be a bit easier since you could consider, for example, at least 1 '6' $1-(1-\frac{1}{6})^4$ etc

Comment: @Jules: OK, after a mistake, and browser trouble, I corrected the "fast" way. Sorry about the delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Later on, we describe a **fast** solution. But for reasons of nostalgia, we keep our first slow way.

**The slow way:** We assume that the balls are removed one at a time and *not replaced*. Then the probabilities can be found with a careful examination of cases.

With probability $\frac{1}{6}$ we have $X=1$.

We have $X=2$ precisely if we got the sequence $2,1$. This has probability $\frac{1}{6\cdot 5}$.

We have $X=3$ in several  ways: the sequence $3,1$, the sequence $2,3,1$ and the sequence $3,2,1$. The combined probability is $\frac{1}{6\cdot 5}+\frac{2}{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}$.

For the number of ways in which $X=4$, note that this happens with the sequences 
$4,1$, or  $4,2,1$, or $2,4,1$, or $3,4,1$ or $4,3,1$,  or 
$x,y,z,1$, where $x,y,z$ is one of the $6$ permutations of $2,3,4$. The probability is $\frac{1}{6\cdot 5}+\frac{4}{6\cdot 5\cdot 4}+ \frac{6}{6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3}$.

And so on. Actually, we are almost finished, since once we find $\Pr(X=5)$, we know $\Pr(X=8)$, since the probabilities add to $1$. It may still be a good idea to do an independent computation of $\Pr(X=6)$, as a check.

Once we have the probability distribution of $X$, finding $E(X)$ is mechanical.

**A much faster way**: The computations can be streamlined. Let us find $\Pr(X\le 5)$. This is the probability that $6$ comes **after** $1$. By symmetry this is $\frac{1}{2}$. So $\Pr(X=6)=\Pr(X\le 6)-\Pr(X\le 5)=\frac{1}{2}$.

To find $\Pr(X=5)$, we calculate $\Pr(X\le 5)-\Pr(X\le 4)$. The probability that $X$ is $\le 4$ is the probability $1$ comes before $5$ and $6$, which is $\frac{1}{3}$. So $\Pr(X=5)=\frac{1}{6}$.

To find $\Pr(X= 4)$, we find $\Pr(X\le 4)-\Pr(X\le 3)$. The probability that $X$ is $\le 3$ is the probability that $1$ comes before $4$, $5$, and $6$. This is $\frac{1}{4}$, so $\Pr(X=4)=\frac{1}{12}$.

Continue, it's almost over.

The idea works smoothly for balls numbered $1$ to $n$.

**Remarks:** $1.$ The "fast" method can be adapted to sampling with replacement. 
We calculate, as a sample, the probability that $X$ is $\le 4$. This can happen in various ways: First is $6$, first is between $2$ and $4$ and the second is a $1$, first $2$ are between $2$ and $4$ and the third is a $1$, and so on. The probability is given by 
$$\Pr(X\le 4)=\frac{1}{6}\left(1+\frac{3}{6}+\frac{3^2}{6^2}+\cdots           \right).$$ 
Thus $\Pr(X\le 4)=\frac{1}{3}$. Similarly, we can calculate $\Pr(X\le 3)$, and then by subtraction $\Pr(X=4)$. If we compare with the numbers obtained in the no replacement case, we will notice something interesting.

$2.$ There is a fancier, but ultimately faster way of finding $E(X)$, the method of *indicator* random variables. This can be done without finding the distribution of $X$. But since we were asked to find that distribution, we might as well use it.